# Por que não é exibida a mensagem de erro?

Tags: jquery.validate

Estou treinando um código php para cadastro de usuários, onde é validado os campos necessários porém somente o retorno do campo login que utilizo o comando `remote`: ele não imprime o resultado, eis os códigos que estou utilizando:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Cadstro de usuarios</title>
    <link href="theme/css/principal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#idForm").validate({
                // Define as regras
                rules: {
                    txtNome: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                    txtEmail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    txtLogin: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4,
                        remote: 'checa_login.php'

                    },
                    txtSenha: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                    rep_senha: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: "#txtSenha"
                    }
                },
                // Define as mensagens de erro para cada regra
                messages: {
                    txtNome: {
                        required: 'Digite o seu nome',
                        minlength: 'O seu nome deve conter, no mínimo, 4 caracteres'
                    },
                    txtEmail: {
                        required: 'Digite o seu e-mail para contato',
                        email: 'Digite um e-mail válido'
                    },
                    txtLogin: {
                        required: 'E necessario cadstrar um login',
                        minlength: 'O seu login deve conter, no mínimo, 4 caracteres',
                        remote: 'Este login ja esta em uso.'
                    },
                    txtSenha: {
                        required: 'Digite uma senha',
                        minlength: 'A senha deve ter no mínimo, 4 caracteres'
                    },
                    rep_senha: {
                        required: 'Repita sua a mesma senha',
                        equalTo: 'A senha n&atilde;o &eacute; igual a anterior.'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" name="idForm" id="idForm">
        <fieldset id="centro">
            <legend>Cadastro de novo usuário</legend>
            <label for="nome">Nome: *</label>
            <input id="nome" name="txtNome" type="text" />
            <br />
            <label for="email">E-Mail: *</label>
            <input id="email" name="txtEmail" type="text" />
            <br />
            <label for="login">Login: *</label>
            <input id="login" name="txtLogin" type="text" />
            <br />
            <label for="senha">Senha: *</label>
            <input id="txtSenha" name="txtSenha" type="password" />
            <br />
            <label for="rep_senha">Re-digitar senha: *</label>
            <input id="rep_senha" name="rep_senha" type="password" />
            <br>
            <br />
            <input name="cmd" type="submit" id="cmd" value="Cadastrar" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

O código php que verifica a existência do login é este:

```php
<?php
    include_once( 'login/conect.php' ); 
    $result = '';
    $username = $_GET['txtLogin'];
    $db = conect::getInstance(); 
    $e = $db-> prepare ( "SELECT * FROM  `login` WHERE login ='$username'" ); 
    $e->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $e -> execute ( ) ; 
    if ($e->rowCount() > 0 ){
        echo json_encode('Login ja em uso.');
        exit;
    }else{
        echo json_encode('true');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Precisei colocar o `exit;` para sumir com a quebra linha que estava vindo junto.
O estranho é que somente o `remote` não esta funcionando na verificação de vazio ou de tamanho, funciona corretamente pois imprime na tela adequadamente.